# Normal convergence of series when the definition holds only for $n>n_0$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Consider a series of real functions $\sum_{n\geq 0} u_n(x)$. **Normal convergence** in  a subset $S\subset \mathbb{R}$ requires that:

> $$\exists\,\, M_{n}>0 : \sum_{n \geq 0} M_n
> \,\,\,\,\mathrm{converges}\,\,\,\, \mathrm{and} \,\,\, \,\,\, |u_{n}(x)|\leq M_n \,\,,\,\forall x \in S   \,\,,\, \forall n \geq ...
> \tag{1} $$

Where I put $...$ on textbook I found "$\forall n \geq 0$".

---

I would like to know how to prove rigorously the two following facts (which I'm assuming true):

1. $\sum_{n \geq 0} u_n(x)$ converges normally $\iff$ $\sum_{n \geq n_0} u_n(x)$ converges normally
2. If the inequality in $(1)$ holds only for $n \geq n_0 >0$, the series $\sum_{n \geq 0} u_n(x)$ and $\sum_{n \geq n_0} u_n(x)$ both converge normally

Comment: Your definition of normal convergence seems to depend on $0$ as the starting index. What are we then supposed to make of a statement like "$\sum_{n=3}^\infty u_n(x)$ converges normally."

Comment: @zhw Thanks for the comment, that's why I left a blank space where in the definition there is $n \geq $. Is the normal convergence defined in some other way than the one in question? That's the only definition I found of normal convergence, if you know where I can find another one could you please suggest me?

Comment: Hard to make anything out of this without proper definitions.

Answer (score 1):

The nature convergence (pointwise, uniform., absolut or normal), doesn't  depend on$\;n_0$, since it depends only on the limit when $n \to +\infty$, but the limit function

$S(x)$ depends strongly on $n_0$,since

$$S(x)=\sum_{n=n_0}^{+\infty} u_n(x)$$

Answer (score 0):

The equivalence of the two holds, provided that all the $u_n$'s are *bounded* in $S$, and hence $\,M_n=\sup_{x\in S}\lvert u_n(x)\rvert<\infty$.

Take for example $S=(0,1/2)$, and $u_n(x)=x^{n-1}$. Clearly, $M_0=\infty$, $M_n=2^{-n+1}$, and
$$
\sum_{n\ge 0}M_n=\infty, \quad\text{while}\quad \sum_{n\ge 1}M_n=2.
$$

Assume now that $\,M_n=\sup_{x\in S}\lvert u_n(x)\rvert<\infty$, for all $n\ge 0$. Let $n_0\ge 0$. Clearly, if the sum $\sum_{n\ge n_0}M_n$ converges the so does the sum
$$
\sum_{n\ge 0}M_n=(M_0+\cdots+ M_{n_0-1})+\sum_{n\ge n_0}M_n.
$$
The above identity implies also the inverse.

Therefore, the series $\,\sum_{n\ge n_0}u_n(x)\,$ converges normally if and only if the series $\,\sum_{n\ge 0}u_n(x)\,$ converges normally.